# Efficiently Storing Chat Logs and Displaying Real-Time Activity Graphs

Tags: mysql, database, logging, statistics, real-time

At the present time, I wish to do some data mining projects/research regarding chat messages. I have a source that delivers chat messages at the rate of **~10 messages/second** throughout the entire day. Every message has the following information, and I would like to store all of the information, for every message:

```
ID, CHANNEL, DATE, USER, MESSAGE
```

I want to be able to show **real-time statistics** that **rank** the CHANNEL/USER based on how many MESSAGES it has RECEIVED/SENT, respectively, within the following time intervals:

```
This Minute, This Hour, This Day, This Month, This Year
```

I also wish to efficiently graph the activity (through MESSAGE counts) for any specific CHANNEL or USER or a combination of both over a **specified period of time** with a **specified level of precision** for counting MESSAGES.

Q1: What kind of database setup should I used that would allow for efficiently storing all this information?

Q2: What kind of methodology should I use to display the aforementioned real-time information to multiple clients as efficiently and quickly as possible?

Thanks.